# Check if string contains "µg" JavaScript special Characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, special-characters, contains

im trying to get products from database and make some conditions to my product dose :

im trying :

```
if (product.dose.indexOf('\u00b5') > -1) {
        product.unite = 'µg';
       // i tried too : product.unite = '\u00b5'
}
```

then i tried too :

```
if (product.dose.indexOf('µg') > -1) {
        product.unite = 'µg';
}
```

But not working

Thank you in advance :)

Edit : i have 5 unity in my database product dose is a string that can be '15  g' or '20 µg' for ex so i made all conditions for all units possible to find in dose column for my product :

```
   if (product.dose.indexOf('\u00b5') > -1){
       product.unite = "µg";     
    } else if ((product.dose.indexOf("g") > -1) && (product.dose.indexOf('\u00b5')==-1)) {
product.unite = "g";      }...
```

but i get  'g' sometimes , and µg sometimes as unity when its really 'µg' in database

Comment: what is not working ??

Comment: What exactly is not working? What diagnostic output is there? What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: i have 5 unity in my database product dose is a string that can be '15  g' or '20 µg' for ex so i made all conditions for all units possible to find in dose column for my product : 

      ` if (product.dose.indexOf('\u00b5') > -1) {        product.unite = "µg";      } else if ((product.dose.indexOf("g") > -1) && (product.dose.indexOf('\u00b5')==-1)) {        product.unite = "g";      }...`
but i get all the time 'g' as unity when its really 'µg' in database  (sorry marked code but not working)

Comment: `console.log(product.dose)`. What exactly *does* your string contain...?!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, my code was ok its my database that is not working well,

data was entered from excel import , so sometimes somes characters are not really like we see them:

in our example in my database dose column for the product where i had errors :

"for 25 µg" , so i rewrite it with same " for 25 µg' and its working now

so i have a question : why we have errors like those ? if you could explain me iwill apreciate it :)

Thank you so much for your time and for your disponibilty